# Why are some of my photos coming out almost completely purple?

Tags: troubleshooting, point-and-shoot, panasonic, data-corruption

Some of photos that I took look like this [one](https://plus.google.com/photos/109484369809436761089/albums/5761303114505930945). Look at the purple picture, it is supposed to be exactly the same as the one on the right-wall, window, etc. Nothing purple in it at all. This happens more often in open air / sunny weather but from time to time it happens randomly as well. I noticed that chances are higher if I take longer to focus/zoom, etc. At other times, photos look perfect. I tried to  reset everything, adjust white colour settings, etc, but it does not seem to help much. I also tried different memory cards and still having the same problem.

My camera is Panasonic Lumix DMC-ZX1 and I'm shooting JPEG.

Comment: Which are the bad colour images. Are you referring to the purple part or the though window view or views or ...?  What should the purple area look like?

Comment: I agree with Russel, you'll need to provide some more information about the purle image and the window scene. I assume the purple part is a 100% crop of a specific purple area on the wall looking through the window?

Also could you mention what type of camera is this from? and also is the output image RAW or jpeg?

Comment: I'd describe that purple as more than "off". Do the wrong pictures always have that problem?

Comment: As an artifact it almost looks like a dithered image with excessive saturation of a badly exposed scene. Definitely more than just a little "off"

Comment: Thanks guys and sorry for not providing more information. Camera is Panasonic Lumix DMC-ZX1. All images are .jpeg The purple picture is supposed to be exactly the same as the one on the right-wall, window, etc. Nothing purple in it at all. All wrong pictures have the same problem-actual view is not recognizable and everything is covered in bright purple. Thanks guys again!

Comment: That's more than the colours being "off", that looks like a totally spurious image! Have you tried different memory cards?

Comment: I have not tried different memory cards, but would not be the issue for all pictures not just for some?

Comment: No faulty memory cards aren't predictable, so if you can try another memory card that will help in narrowing down the problem

Comment: Can you confirm that it happens more the longer you operate the camera before taking the shot? It may be heat-related.

Comment: Yes, it is usually the case. What do you mean by 'heat related'?

Comment: @Justas - can't see the linked image, could you possibly upload it to the site or fix the permissions to make it public?

Comment: @Justas: Your image is NOT publicly visible. Everyone is getting error responses or login request screens. You really need to make it public.

Comment: This member has not been back since asking this question. The image will most likely not be updated. Please refrain from flagging the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @jrista Maybe at this point we should just close the question?

Comment: Looks like you guys got it taken care of.

Answer (score 5):

From the Exif Info,
The normal photo has exposure 1/60s, ISO 80 and f4.9 without flash, focal length 13.6mm.
The purple one has exposure 1/60s, ISO 1000 and f5.9 with flash, focal length 33mm.  This picture should have been overexposed by at least 3 stops + flash if you had taken it with the same lighting as the normal picture.

Its possible that the flash is throwing off your white balance... it could also be that the camera thinks that that it is using a flash (while it does not fire) and over compensates for the white balance.

I would check the Exif info of all the ones that are purple, see if it says flash is on and may be that is the reason it ended up messing up your white balance.

Answer (score 1):

I would say 100% you have a faulty camera or memory card.
(assuming they appear like this on both the camera and computer)

Try another memory card, failing that take your camera back to the shop.

Comment: Tried a different memory card-result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem.  Tried every setting.  Guru friend told me that light defraction (either shutter not fully open or dirt on the lens) will cause colour change in the photos (and thro the view-finder).  Cleaned the lens and viola, no more purple.

Comment: Have you seen the sample photos linked to the question? If not, then how do you know your problem was the same?